# Unknown column in 'where clause?

Tags: php, mysql

I Have the following code of php

```
        $query = sprintf("SELECT to_go.to_location FROM to_go 
                INNER JOIN to_location ON to_go.to_location_id = to_location.id 
                    WHERE match(to_location ) against(%s)", mysql_real_escape_string($location));
```

i tried every thing but it keep output me that following error "Unknown column in 'where clause ?" i tried to change the names of the columns and still the same problem

Comment: hard to judge without the tables. one way of testing is to write the sql and substitute the variables etc. and then run it at the sql command line or in a mysql query tool. you will get better diagnostics and better visibility of the errors

Answer (score 2):

`match(to_location ) against` needs to be provided a field, not a table:

```
match(to_location.id) against(something)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may need to replace

```
WHERE match(to_location )
```

with

```
WHERE match(to_go.to_location)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a column name the same name as a table name, MySql is probably confusing them and thinking `match(to_location)` refers to the table.  Try using the fully-qualified column name, i.e., `table_name.column_name`.